# Atomic Transaction with nested BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE Triggers

Tags: database, oracle, transactions, database-trigger

Currently i am implementing a procedure, which creates a couple of rows in some related tables out of a template. So my Procedure consists of a `SAVEPOINT` followed by some `INSERT` statements on different tables, and a Cursor to insert some more rows to other tables while referencing on the newly created primary keys.

Each of those tables has an BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE trigger defined which has the purpose to:

- Get a new primary key from a sequencer if it is not defined in the INSERT statement (there are cases where I need to set the Primary key explicitely to reference it later on in the same transaction)
- Set some default values if they are NULL
- Set auditing fields (last_change_date, last_change_user, etc..)

The transaction fails with *ORA-04091: table  is mutating, trigger/function may not see it*

I am understanding, that I could Workaround this, by declaring PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION in each Trigger, but my Transaction would not be atomic any more then, as it is the requirement that all those datasets should be created/inserted as a whole or None of them.

So what am I doing wrong in the design of my database?

---

**UPDATE**: This is the Code of the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_AUFTRAG_B_IU
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON AUFTRAG
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    IF INSERTING THEN
    IF :new.id is NULL or :new.id = 0 THEN
      SELECT SEQ_AUFTRAG.nextval into :new.id from dual;
    END IF;

    IF :new.nummer is NULL or :new.nummer = 0 THEN
      SELECT nvl(MAX(NUMMER),0)+1 INTO :new.nummer FROM AUFTRAG WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR from DATUM) = EXTRACT(YEAR from :new.DATUM);
    END IF;

    --DEFAULT Values
    IF :new.BETR_GRENZWERTE_RELEVANT is NULL THEN
      SELECT 0 INTO :new.BETR_GRENZWERTE_RELEVANT FROM dual;
    END IF;

    IF :new.DOKUMENTE_ABGELEGT is NULL THEN
      SELECT 0 INTO :new.DOKUMENTE_ABGELEGT FROM dual;
    END IF;

    IF :new.EXT_ORG is NULL or :new.EXT_ORG < 1 THEN
      SELECT 1 INTO :new.EXT_ORG FROM dual;
    END IF;

    :new.ERSTELLT_VON := nvl(:new.ERSTELLT_VON,user);
    :new.ERSTELLT_DATUM := nvl(:new.ERSTELLT_DATUM,sysdate);
    END IF;

    :new.GEAENDERT_VON := user;
    :new.GEAENDERT_DATUM := sysdate;
    END;
```

Comment: Please show us the code of your trigger. Actually the actions you list are very typical and useful for triggers, they should work without any problem.

Comment: It appears that you are performing a `select` from the same table within the trigger.  Based on what you say the trigger need to do, there is no requirement for any `select`.  And you are right - `pragma autonomous transaction` is no solution to this sort of issue.

Comment: ah! I think I already see whats the Problem....it is the :new:NUMMER part isn't it? This is for creating an Identification Number which is a business requirement. Would it be a solution to do this in a AFTER INSERT TRIGGER?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it more compact like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_AUFTRAG_B_IU
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON AUFTRAG
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    IF INSERTING THEN
        :new.id = NVL(NULLIF(:new.id, 0), SEQ_AUFTRAG.nextval);

        --DEFAULT Values
        :new.BETR_GRENZWERTE_RELEVANT := NVL(:new.BETR_GRENZWERTE_RELEVANT, 0);
        :new.DOKUMENTE_ABGELEGT := NVL(:new.DOKUMENTE_ABGELEGT, 0);

        IF :new.EXT_ORG is NULL or :new.EXT_ORG < 1 THEN
          :new.EXT_ORG := 1;
        END IF;    
        :new.ERSTELLT_VON := nvl(:new.ERSTELLT_VON,user);
        :new.ERSTELLT_DATUM := nvl(:new.ERSTELLT_DATUM,sysdate);
    END IF;

    :new.GEAENDERT_VON := user;
    :new.GEAENDERT_DATUM := sysdate;
END;
```

Only "problem" is this part

```
IF :new.nummer is NULL or :new.nummer = 0 THEN
    SELECT nvl(MAX(NUMMER),0)+1 INTO :new.nummer 
    FROM AUFTRAG 
    WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR from DATUM) = EXTRACT(YEAR from :new.DATUM);
END IF;
```

This one you should put into your procedure or in a statement trigger (i.e. without `FOR EACH ROW` clause) like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_AUFTRAG_B_A
  AFTER INSERT ON AUFTRAG
BEGIN
    UPDATE 
        (SELECT ID, NUMMER,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR from DATUM) ORDER BY ID) as N
        FROM AUFTRAG)
    SET NUMMER = N
    WHERE NUMMER IS NULL;        
END;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not only for making these concepts - mutating tables - clear to me, but also for suggesting code improvements.